Bootstrap Table Resizable Columns
I have found this documentation about resizable columns on bootstrap tables.
However i'm having a hard time understanding how to make a html table object to use this functionality. Could someone provide an example on how to use this?
I found this stackoverflow post about it but it was not what i was looking for since it uses split.js

Pls provide your code attempt for help.

Here's the official example from Bootstrap Table Examples:


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-resizable-columns@0.2.3/dist/jquery.resizableColumns.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-table@1.22.4/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-resizable-columns@0.2.3/dist/jquery.resizableColumns.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-table@1.22.4/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-table@1.22.4/dist/extensions/resizable/bootstrap-table-resizable.min.js"></script>

<table id="table"
  data-show-columns="true"
  data-search="true"
  data-show-toggle="true"
  data-pagination="true"
  data-url="json/data1.json"
  data-resizable="true">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">ID</th>
      <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Item Name</th>
      <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Item Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable()
  })
</script>




tks!! i didn't found this earlier
